# ElasticSearch 6.x : Make more short syntax

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I want make to search this sentence.

```
title: Change my room!
description: I change my desk and chair. These make my room more beautiful!
```

I want to search user query on each section, title, description.
And I make query syntax on server side. For example, when user send query,

```
query: change desk chair
```

then server make like this

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "description": "change"
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "description": "desk"
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "description": "chair"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "title": "change"
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "title": "desk"
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "title": "chair"
                }
              }
            ]
          }    
        }
      ]   
    }
  }
}
```

Can I short this query syntax?

Answer (score -1):

You can use query_string or match query for doing this.

example:

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -d '
{
      "query": { "match": { "_all": "Change my room" } }
}'
```

or

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -d '{
      "query": { "query_string": { "query": "Change my room" } }
}'
```

Comment: It's not act to exactly. I want to search include all keywords.